# DatePickerDialog NPE

Tags: android

Why do I get a NPE (return dialog is null) with the following?

```
public class ViewCalendar extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {
    private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

The following does work. Why?

```
public class ViewCalendar extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {
    private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think context (this) was getting Null. You need to debug that.

Comment: `getActivity()` is null

Comment: Besides `this` write `getActivity().this` and try. @Nfear

Comment: in Java, the keyword `this` will never be `null`. I don't about other Languages much like .NET

Comment: @Nfear how do you know `getActivity` is not null

Comment: `getActivity()` returns `null` until `onAttach()`is called.

Comment: @Nfear you can look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html. You will know yourself. `this` refers to `ViewCalendar` which ` `implements OnDateSetListener`. hence `this` is the second param. `getActivity` is null

Comment: I see now. Thank you. Last thing I am not sure about is why I should change this to getActivity().this

Comment: @Nfear no need for that. `getActivity` returns the activity which hosts this fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java (I don't know much about other languages) , the global(instance) fields will be initialized immediately after the object is Constructed(instance created). so when you declare Dialog as field like

```
public class Sampple extends Fragment {
     private DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 }
```

here `Dialog` will be initialzed after Constructor call and still `onAttach()` is not called. thus here `getActivity()` returns null

Comment: How can the dialog be constructed if the Calendar hasn't been initialized yet? If you say that the field will be initialized after the object has been created, how is this possible?

Comment: you are getting NPE only because of getActivity(). it does not matter how you declared Calender as global instance or local field...